# Adding multiple items to combo box only adds LAST ITEM

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm trying to add multiple items to a combobox but only the last item is showing.

Example:

```
Dim i as Integer
   For i = 0 to 3
   AddItemToComboBox(i, i)
Next

Sub AddItemToComboBoxMod(ByVal itmValue, ByVal itmData)
        Dim comboSource As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        comboSource.Add(itmValue, itmData)
        cbComboBox.DataSource = New BindingSource(comboSource, Nothing)
        cbComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value"
        cbComboBox.ValueMember = "Key"
        Dim key As String = DirectCast(cbComboBox.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Key
        Dim value As String = DirectCast(cbComboBox.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Value
    End Sub
```

BUT at the end, only the last item "3" will be there.   0,1,2 will be missing.

Why?

Comment: because you are creating a new comboSource each time, which flushes anything previously entered into the bit bucket. Try populating the comboSource in your loop, then set the datasource of the combobox ONCE.

Comment: Okay, What I tried now was making the comboSource a Public item, but its still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this too complicated.
Populate the values you want in the list.
THEN set the DataSource property ONCE. In above code, you are setting the DataSource property in each iteration of the loop.

Below is a sample event handler that I put together to demonstrate the concept.

```
Private Sub cmdPopulate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPopulate.Click
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim comboSource As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()

        For i = 0 To 3
            comboSource.Add(i, i)
        Next



        cbComboBox.DataSource = New BindingSource(comboSource, Nothing)
        cbComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value"
        cbComboBox.ValueMember = "Key"

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are creating a new Dictionary every time you call AddItemToComboBoxMod(). You might want to instantiate it and bind it somewhere else. The add item method should only be appending the key value pair.